# mpdf not working [Fatal error: Trait 'Mpdf\Strict' not found]

Tags: php, mpdf

I have downloaded the updated version of mpdf and using it with php. It is giving me the following error.

> "fatal error: Trait 'Mpdf\Strict' not found in
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\PDF\mpdf\Mpdf.php on line 39".

```
$html = '<h2>mpdf test.</h2>';

include("mpdf/mpdf.php");

$mpdf = new mPDF('c','A4','','',32,25,27,25,16,13); 

$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');

$mpdf->list_indent_first_level = 0; // 1 or 0 - whether to indent the first 
 level of a list

// LOAD a stylesheet
$stylesheet = file_get_contents('mpdfstyletables.css');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);    // The parameter 1 tells that this is css/style only and no body/html/text

$mpdf->WriteHTML($html,2);

$mpdf->Output('mpdf.pdf','I');
exit;
```

Comment: is this file present in location? also change include to require_once

Comment: Yes the file is present

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are directly including mpdf via

```
include("mpdf/mpdf.php");
```

which will only include the core file but not any other file mPDF may need in the generation process. The correct way would be to use:

```
// Require composer autoload
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
// Create an instance of the class:
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
```

This will make sure that required classes will be autoloaded as soon as they are referenced.

For more info, check the ["Getting started"](https://mpdf.github.io/getting-started/creating-your-first-file.html) chapter on the mPDF web page.

Answer (score 0):

if ($this->bodyBackgroundColor{0} == 5) { // RGBa
Severity: Compile Error

Message: Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is no longer supported

Filename: src/Mpdf.php

Line Number: 2238

Backtrace:

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).